# Unable to link my jquery file to my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm unable to link my jquery to my html. It's such a simple step but is driving me nuts. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> Hucke Buckle Project </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="huckle.css">
     <script src= "huckle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src = "jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src ="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <form>
        <input type="number" class="num" name="number"><br>
    </form>

    <div id="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="subm" > Submit </button>
        <button type="reset" class="reset"> Reset </button>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

My HTML and jQuery files are in the same folder and I cannot figure out why they are not linking.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var i=0;
    var scopedVal;
    var checkNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    alert(checkNum);
    /*var hotCheck = function(scopedVal, submitVal) {
                if (Math.abs(checkNum - scopedVal) >= Math.abs(checkNum - submitVal))
                        {
                        alert("hotter, try again!");
                        }
                  else { alert("colder, try again!");}
                  }

        */        
    $('.subm').on('click', function() {

    i++;
    /*var submitVal = $(this).closest('form').find('.num').val();
    alert('submitval is' + submitVal);
    if(checkNum === submitVal)
    { alert('Got IT!');}
    else {if(i<=1){
        alert('try again');
        scopedVal = submitVal;
        }
        else {
        hotCheck(scopedVal, submitVal);
        scopedVal = submitVal;
        }
        }
        */
        });

        });
```

Comment: What's the console error?

Comment: your ordering is wrong is wrong put jquery on top in scripts

Comment: @EhsanSajjad any way the code is in `ready()` so does it matter..?

Comment: @TJ Yes, because of the `$` in `$(document).ready`

Comment: @Aditya, what is the name of your javascript file?

Comment: oh, right. and i guess `var i=0;` should be outside `ready()`

Comment: Changing the order worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts are loaded in the WRONG order.

You have

1. yours
2. migrate
3. jQuery

It should be

1. jQuery
2. migrate
3. yours

Comment: Downvoted because answer is already provided in comments and user ackowledged issue was fixed

Comment: He is being facetious at your expense @deweyredman. Just because the question was answered in a comment doesn't mean that there isn't a valid answer worth posting. Now upvote this back so epascarello can eat tacos this weekend.

Comment: My point is what is the point of answering the question if the user has already gotten what he needs?  Purely for reputation?

Comment: Dude, I never read the comments. I looked at the code saw the issue right away and posted it. I can not believe it took 10 minutes of questions before someone saw it... Question should be closed anyway since question is useless.

Comment: i posted answer in comment so may i post answer and you all upvote it..LOL...:D

Comment: The question was asked 16 minutes ago and an answer was posted 15 minutes ago, i'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Not sure I agree that it's useless.  To newer developers it might prove useful to have this question here.

Comment: I see, I looked for a duplicate to flag it about 10 minutes ago, but I couldn't find one.  Feel free to do so yourself if you have better luck, lol